# Automatically list all folders of a location on server

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Im wondering if there is a way to list all my client folders from a php file, but because im running on a Drupal website, when i go to the location of client folders for their websites, i get a 404 page because it thinks its a drupal page i am looking for .. therefore i want to make the page that its trying to land on, and make that page list the folders of that url.

the url is simplemedia.dk/kunder/ - instead of listing all subfolders it shows what you can see ..

if i enter full url simplemedia.dk/kunder/merkur i get the clients website as im suppose to.

I figured PHP is the thing i need.

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin149's on the right track. As you seemed to only want to list subfolders, glob has a `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag. This will ignore any files that are in the directory, and because you want to put a PHP script in the kunder directory, this will be not show up here (as you're only looking for directories).

```
<ul>
<?php foreach (glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir): ?>
    <li><a href='./<?php echo $dir ?>'><?php echo $dir ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: this seemed to work for me the way i wanted .. except now it is showing the root folder in the list, but i want it to show a subfolder .. where do i add the subfolder path? the path for the list i wish to display.

Comment: The first argument of glob, "\*", is the filter. So you'd modify it to e.g., glob("kunder/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR).

Comment: When i use the provided code, it shows only "kunder" as a link, where i want it to show the contents of "kunder" which is ofcourse only folders with installations.

Comment: tried, but now i get kunder/kunder/clientfolder because the page i am trying to show the list on, is called simplemedia.dk/kunder/ .. i tried playing with the ./kunder/* but i cant seem to get the desired result..

Answer (score 2):

An entry in your .htaccces file should be enough to make this work. Put your client sites in a subfolder so the url would look like simplemedia.dk/kunder/clients/merkur.

First, modify the Drupal .htaccess

```
# don't rewrite urls like this
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/clients/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

Then add a .htaccess file to your clients folder with this entry

```
Options +Indexes
```

Which will list the contents of the directory. As long as you only have client folders in that directory you don't have to worry about limiting the list to directories.

I just ran a quick test and while Alex's code is correct, it wouldn't run in the context of a Drupal site without some .htaccess magic. The built in rewrite rule will still modify the request and Drupal  will give you a 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo "<a href='./{$filename}'>{$filename}</a><br />\n";
}
?>
```

This should output a list of all files in a given directory